# How to confirm hive mode of running in CDH 4.2? - local or remote

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

In my cluster, that uses CDH 4.2, I see two different hive-site.xml files.
1. hive-site.xml file that is in the hive conf directory.
2. hive-site.xml file that I can view from the WebUI of CDH 4.2

My problem is that both these files have different content in terms of hive execution mode.
hive-site.xml file in the conf directory lists the mode of execution as "remote". It has "false" as the value of the parameter - hive.metastore.local and it also defines the parameter - >hive.metastore.uris as -

```
thrift://<machine_name>:9083
```

But the hive-site.xml file that I can view using WebUI, lists the local mode as true and sets the following parameters.

```
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:postgresql://<machine_name>:7432/hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
  </property>
```

I think it is running in local mode, because the WebUI also states that hive metastore is running in the hive process and listening on port 9083.
Also, per configuration, hiveserver2 should be running on port 10000 by default, which is not the case.

So I have two queries
1. Why are there 2 different configuration XML files?
2. Is there a "litmus" test to confirm that hive is indeed is running in local mode?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per the explanation of the Jira ticket  [Collapse hive.metastore.uris and hive.metastore.local](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2585), if the property `hive.metastore.uris` is set, which in your case, the Hive metastore will be running in remote mode. If the property `hive.metastore.uris` is not set, then Hive metastore will be running in local mode.

The above also implies that the property `hive.metastore.local` is removed as of Hive 0.10 which is the version in CDH4.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely make sure you have the following in your hive-site.xml.

```
<property>
    <name> hive.metastore.local</name>
    <value>false</value> 
 </property> 
 <property>
    <name> hive.metastore.uris</name>
 <value>thrift://<hive_metastore_server_host>:9083</value> 
</property>
```

To your second question, a good test is to run a quick hive query. Once the MR job starts to spin up you will see whether or not it is point to the JobTracker on your cluser or in local mode.